# converting string of numbers to numbers

Tags: c, string

When I try to convert string_1="20001" using the code below, I get the array: string_1[0]=2 and string_1[1]=0. what is the reason behind that ? when it's "20125" it's okay but when it's more than one zero it's not okay.

```
    for(j=0;j<strlen(string_1);j++)
    {
        string_1[j]=(string_1[j]-8)%10;
    }
```

What I expect to get is : `string_1[0]=2 , string_1[1]=0 , string_1[3]=0 ,string_1[3]=0 and string_1[4]=1`.

Comment: Even if you get this working, how are you going to tell the difference between a zero in the string and the terminating null in the resulting string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are modifying the string in the loop, which means the condition no longer will work as you call `strlen(string_1)` every iteration (remember that `strlen` looks for the string termination `'\0'` which is equal to zero to find the end).

Either get the length once before and put it in a variable you use in the condition, or use another array for the destination.